# Latest google drive API update

Tags: google-drive-api

In the latest Google Drive API update, they want us to provide them with a `resourceKey`, when we want to access the Google Drive shared link. They said they put the resource key in the metadata of the files, but when I get the metadata of the files, there is no `resourceKey` attribute in there. So, do you guys know how to get the `resourceKey` of the file?

Metadata request code :

```
$fileID = substr($url,strpos($url,'=')+1,33);
$metadata=\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk("google")->getMetaData($fileID);
```

[image: the metadata result]

Comment: To improve your question, you could show a code snippet of how you're requesting the metadata, so it's clear that you're including `resourceKey` in the list of fields to return from your call.  I have the same problem of not getting the `resourceKey` when I make a `drive.files.get` request though, so I know that it doesn't help - but it would be the obvious thing to check, so it would help to show that you're doing the request right.

Comment: I already include the metadata request code, you can take e look at it @RobertRendell

Comment: It looks like this similar question has an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68777408/how-to-obtain-a-resourcekey-using-google-drive-api