# How to obtain a resourceKey using Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

With the recent security update for Drive document URLs and resource key https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resource-keys it's not clear how to get the resource key using the API. For instance the `create` method doesn't return `resourceKey`, only `id` :

```
drive.files.create {
  resource: fileMetadata
  media: media
  fields: 'id,resourceKey,shortcutDetails'
}, (err, body) ->
  ...
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the files metadata after it was created?

Comment: @JasonE. yes I did `drive.files.get` request after a file was created but couldn't find `resourceKey` in the response body.

Comment: Have you applied the update already? See here https://support.google.com/a/answer/10685032?hl=en

Comment: @JasonE. thanks for the link, I've found some affected files at https://drive.google.com/drive/update-files/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx with 'Remove security update' button. Those files were shared with me. Looks like if I have some Google Docs files on a Regular Gmail account (on behalf of which i made api requests), not on the Google Workspace account, the security change shouldn't affect me.

Comment: I've posted an answer below so that users can see what needs to be done in order for resourceKey to work on their end.

Comment: Another info : Phase 3: Drive enforces update—Beginning September 13, 2021
The update should finish by the end of September 2021.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security update needs to be applied in order for the resourceKey to be useable to you.

To apply the security update:

1. From the Admin console Home page, go to Apps and then Google Workspace and then Drive and Docs.
2. Click Sharing settings and then Security update for files.
3. Choose how to apply the update:
   -Apply the security update to all impacted files
   -Remove security update from all impacted files (not recommended)
4. (Optional if applying the update) To let users remove or apply the update to files that they own or manage, check the allow box.
5. If you made any changes, click Save.

Reference:
[Decide how to apply link-sharing security update to Drive](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10685032?hl=en)

Comment: For personal Google accounts, it seems that "the security update is applied by default and no action is required", presumably on or after the September 13th 2021 deadline - https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10729743