# How to get file with resourcekey Google Drive API?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I found here

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68777408/how-to-obtain-a-resourcekey-using-google-drive-api
```

and

```
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resource-keys
```

I did get resourcekey of folder/file. But how to get copy file or folder with resourcekey?
I use code

```
DriveService.Files.Get(id).Execute()
```

It work update before. But now don't. I search many post but don't solve. Sorry my English not good. Thank for read.
Edit: I use C#.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what are you trying to do? It seems unclear from the post.

Comment: @Kessy: Before Google Drive security update, this code work
DriveService.Files.Get(id).Execute()
After update it error for resourcekey share link. I try fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `X-Goog-Drive-Resource-Keys` header in your request. The simplest way to do that in the client libraries is via request interceptors. It's a little clunky, but not actually complicated:

```cs
public class HeaderExecuteInterceptor : IHttpExecuteInterceptor
{
    private readonly string header;
    private readonly string value;

    public HeaderExecuteInterceptor(string header, string value)
    {
        this.header = header;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Task InterceptAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add(header, value);
        // The value doesn't matter; Task.CompletedTask is simpler where supported.
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}


// Where you make the request
const string ResourceKeysHeader = "X-Goog-Drive-Resource-Keys";
var request = service.Files.Get(id);
var interceptor = new HeaderExecuteInterceptor(ResourceKeysHeader, resourceKey);
request.AddExecuteInterceptor(interceptor);
var response = request.Execute();
```

Comment: Maybe the code for Net 5.0? I use 4.5.

Comment: @Afrendly: I suggest you update to a supported (by Microsoft) version of .NET - if `Task.CompletedTask` was causing the problem, that was added in .NET 4.6. In future, if something doesn't work, it's much more helpful to say what problem you're running into (as well as the framework version, particularly if you're on an old, unsupported version). I've changed the code to use `Task.FromResult(true)` which should work on .NET 4.5 though.

Comment: That's my fault. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, anyone can use this code.

```
DriveService.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Goog-Drive-Resource-Keys", "ID/ResourceKey")
DriveService.Files.Get(id).Execute()
```

The "/" is required.